# How can you harvest CKAN datsets using filter

Tags: filter, dataset, ckan, harvest

I'm using CKAN 2.9 version with the Remote harvesting extension.

I don't want to harvest all datasets, I want to harvest select datasets of name or of the ID within packages on a website.

Can I use a filter e.g. with CQL filter in the config or another way possibility (another ext?)?
Do you have an idea of how I can harvest the datasets with a filter and a simple example if I have to use the config?

Answer (score 0):

By default the CKAN harvester extension allows you to filter by organization or group datasets to be included or excluded from harvesting. For e.g  you can harvest the dataset only for a org_1 by adding the  "organizations_filter_include": ['org_1'] key. For more info check the [harvester docs in Github](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-harvest#the-ckan-harvester). If that doesn't work for you, you can use the [IHarvester interface](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-harvest#the-harvesting-interface) and add your own logic, which could be more complicated than using the one above provided by the harvester.